# Efficient storage of matrix from interview questions

Tags: matrix, storage

I had several interviews and failed some of them. 
There was a question actually asked by three different companies. Not exactly the same but they share common structure.

The question is: Now you have a matrix with 0 or 1 (or useful user profile represents by "1" and non useful represents by "0"// or image with 1 and 0 value). Now you need to store the image into the system efficiently. What method should you use?

In my opinion, they were expecting me to come up with efficient solution so I told them using 0, 1 and "value" together.
For example. 00000011100011111
Can be stored as 06 13 03 15
I know there's a encode method similar to this in multimedia or information technology.
But I don't think this is what they want.

And idea?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the meaning of "efficient".

A decent compromise between space and efficiency is to select a native datatype slightly bigger than the number of questions.

I e if you want to store 10 different binary values per item/person, use a `short` (or that's what the 16 bit data type is called in java).

If you store these in an array (`short[]`), you can very quickly find the item/person by it's id, used as a position in the array, and then a certain value by using [bitwise operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) (in this case bitshift a `1` to the position where the interesting item is stored and then use the bitwise operation `&` (and) to get this certain bit out. If the resulting short `!= 0` you know that bit was set.